# Revitalizing two old plums

Tags: tree-care

This is a silhouette of my two plums:

[image]

They are very old, around 10m high, for some longish time left alone, and exude a lot of sap. They have nice fruit. Birds like to rest and observe the area in their high crowns.

Is there anything I can do to revitalize them? Or just leave them as is?

Comment: When you say they emit a lot of sap, what does that mean? Where is the sap coming from?

Comment: From the trunk. @Bamboo

Comment: hmm, well a photo of the area of trunk that's leaking sap would be helpful. Is it leaking amber coloured sap, or clear?

Comment: Amber. @Bamboo There are also several holes with average diameter 8cm in the trunk, made obviously by birds.

Comment: Sounds like gummosis, which may or may not be fatal... photos would be good. Gummosis can be a major problem if there's bacterial (rather than viral, which it probably isn't) involvement, some reading here http://www.100flowers.win/Article/questionandanswer/plantdiseases/201608/2634.html, but photos would still be good. One question though - do you have tree borers in  your country? (we don't in the UK, but they do in the States and other places)

Comment: If birds are making holes in the bark then there is a bigger problem to consider.  Wood peckers aren't doing trial and error holes.  They know that breakfast is right below the bark.  I would get a horticulturalist or arborist out to look at your trees.  You've probably got some bark beetle slowly killing your trees.

Comment: The title of the question is 'revitalizing', not 'killing'.

Answer (score 2):

If the *sap* they are exuding is gelatinous in consistency (and my answer is making that assumption), then it means they have a fungus which is highly contagious to other stone fruit trees. I think you best option would be to cut the trees down, and plant non-stone-fruit trees or wait 3 years and then plant plums of your choice.

Comment: Is 'gelatinous in consistency' = 'consistently gelatinous'? Also, I have no idea how to tell if sap is 'gelatinous'. :)

Comment: If the tree dies, would the virus dissapear?

Comment: Does it look like water or does it look like gelatin? Water makes the tree look wet, gelatin will be thick. The virus will remain in the ground for a few years, you are advised not to plan another prunus tree there for at least 3 years.

Comment: More like gelatin

Comment: Then the trees have the virus. I would have them removed and have the stump removed too if you plan on planting more prunus after waiting a few years

Comment: @Escoce - I never  heard of this virus - can you provide a link or give its name, please?

Comment: @Bamboo Forgive me, I was wrong it's not a virus but fungus. Google "peach tree gelatin" for results including the following in gross paraphrase,  "Cytospora canker, Valsa canker, Coryneum Blight, the fungal cause of gummosis, affects stone fruit trees like apricot, cherry, peach, and plum."

Comment: Erm,  I guessed you mis-spoke - its clear its gummosis, as I say above in the comments, but what's not yet clear is whether is pseudomonas, cytospora or any of the others, need photos for that. Its also not necessarily infectious to other trees...

Comment: If I leave the trees as snags, will the source of infection disappear in three years (just as in the case of roots)?

Comment: No, the fungus incubates in the dead wood and sends spores out into the air in the spring.